# in what situation will an item in System.Collections.Generic.List not be removed successfully?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, generic-list

in what situation will an item in System.Collections.Generic.List not be removed successfully?

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx:

> true if item is successfully removed;
>   otherwise, false. This method also
>   returns false if item was not found in
>   the List(Of T).

The way they phrase it makes me think that it is possible that a Remove operation on an item found in the List(Of T) could actually fail, hence this question.

Comment: I understand it failing if the item was not found, but am also interested as to how else it can fail... Good question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the System.Collections.Generic.List source in Reflector, it would appear that the item not being found in the collection is indeed the only way for Remove to return false.

```
int index = this.IndexOf(item);
if (index >= 0)
{
    this.RemoveAt(index);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can, if you are trying to remove an item that isn't in the list - it is classed as a fail and returns false to show you that nothing was removed.

This can be useful if you then want to do other code if something was actually removed.

**Update:** if your class implements IEquality and that throws an exception, the code lets the throw occur, as in it doesn't get a chance to return.

Coupled with others posting the reflected source, returning false is only when it cannot find an item.

**Update:** further to other  people's source.  If you look at the `IndexOf` chain of methods, you will see that it boils down to equality and does nothing special.

List.Remove:

```
public bool Remove(T item)
{
    int num = this.IndexOf(item);
    if (num >= 0)
    {
        this.RemoveAt(num);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

List.IndexOf:

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    return Array.IndexOf<T>(this._items, item, 0, this._size);
}
```

Array.IndexOf:

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));
    }
    if (count < 0 || count > array.Length - startIndex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Count"));
    }
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.IndexOf(array, value, startIndex, count);
}
```

EqualityComparer.IndexOf:

```
internal virtual int IndexOf(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    int num = startIndex + count;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (this.Equals(array[i], value))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

All code from ILSpy, no thanks to Red Gate :-)

Comment: The MSDN docs quoted state that it returns false if the item was not found in the list, **as well as** if it is not successfully removed...

Answer (score 4):

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public bool Remove(T item)
{
    int index = this.IndexOf(item);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        this.RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code above via reflector. Will only not be removed if it wasn't in the collection. I'm guessing a documentation/language discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

In Mono's source code for comparison:

https://github.com/mono/mono/raw/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs

```
public bool Remove (T item)
{
    int loc = IndexOf (item);
    if (loc != -1)
        RemoveAt (loc);

    return loc != -1;
}
```

So, the documentation is overly fuzzy